# How to garbage collect arrays of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, memory, garbage-collection

I'm working in huge program in java and now I'm trying to avoid loitering to improve it's memory usage, I instantiate some objects in the constructor, and keep instantiated till the end of the program but they are not always used. My question is specificly about garbage collecting arrays of Objects.

For example when the user presses a menu item a JDialog is invoked with lots of components in it, these components were instantiated at the moment that the program runs, but i want to instantiate them when necessary and free them when not.

For example:

```
JRadioButton Options = new JRadioButton[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Options[i] = new JRadioButton(Labels[i]);
}
```

If i want to free the arrays, what shoud i do?

This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Options[i] = null;
    Labels[i] = null;
}
```

Or simply:

```
Options = null;
Labels = null;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: even after these all,keep in mind that  if those arrays are still referenced, they wont be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a Java object will be garbage collected only if it is not reachable (and it might have other references than your array). Then GC runs at nearly unpredictable times (so the memory might be freed much later).

Clearing the array's elements won't release the whole array, but could release each element (provided it becomes unreachable).

setting a variable to `null` might release the array (and of course all the elements).

But for a so small program, perhaps GC is never happening.

Read at least [GC on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), and perhaps the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)

Notice that the aliveness of some object is a whole program property (actually a whole process property: liveness of values is relevant in a particular execution, not in your source code). In other words, you could do `Options = null;` and still have the object in `Options[24]` reachable by some other reference path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Basile So, will just "Options = null" work? About the program, it's a complete database manager for some students registries, so it may be opened like all day long, and just be used when someone want to do a query or add/edit/remove data from the database. Do you consider a good idea freeing arrays of gui components that are just often used?

Answer (score 2):

If `Options` holds the only reference to the array, either works to make the objects unreachable and release the objects to the garbage collector.

If something else is still referencing the array, it won't be released anyway, so the first option is the only one that will release the contents. Note that the first option will *only* release the contents, `Options` will still reference the actual `Array` unless you also set `Options` to null.

Comment: Isn't the GC (if it happens) clever enough to clear up `Options` when the OP does `Options = null`, if there are no external references to the elements?

Comment: Ok, I don't keep any other object referencing the array so i think that saying `options = null` will work, thanks all for your help

Comment: If there were some external references to the elements, what would hold the list itself from being collected?

Comment: Because those external references would be pointing to that portion of memory where the object is located, and while it's beeing referenced it would not be interpreted as garbage. That's what i'm understanding, if i'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: @BheshGurung I can't see where I'm contradicting you, first sentence of my answer says that setting `Options` to null will release all objects to the garbage collector if the array is elsewhere unreferenced. If the array is referenced elsewhere (and thus won't be released) and you want to force all elements to be garbage collected, you need to null out the references individually.

Comment: @user1715408: If there are some reference to some elements means those elements are not ready for collection, doesn't have anything to do with the collection of the list itself, I think.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I just happened to misread the opening sentence of your second paragraph. +1 Actually, it's quite cleverly written.

Comment: Well, as all i want is to reduce memory usage, i will just brute force it and use both hehe

Comment: @JorgeChayan: IMO, it's better to read up a little bit rather than just trying to brute force here.

Answer (score 2):

Doing

```
Options = null;
Labels = null;
```

should be enough to release those objects. There is no need to null the elements unless there is another reference to the array. However when there are other references to the array I do not think it is wise to null the elements. The other references are there for a reason. When they no longer need the array and its contents they should release their references.

Comment: It is enough if no other reference to the objects exist. Otherwise it is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Both will do but first one is recommended and then do second one.

Here is the source code from [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) `clear()` method

```
// Let gc do its work
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    elementData[i] = null;
```

Another way to do same thing is

```
Arrays.fill(Options, null);
```

It does not do any thing different iterates and sets array elements to `null`.

Comment: So should i free each object and then the array itself, both?

Comment: Do you have a reference, where the first one is recommended in regards to releasing a list?